# Multiple nested CSS menu, stretched vertically

Tags: html, css

here is the CSS menu:

http://www.devinrolsen.com/wp-content/themes/dolsen/demos/css/infinite-sub-menu/

as you can see, its perfect, deeply-nested - but not 100% widthed. This is what I want to be 100% stretched. If there are 4 menu items, its width must be 25% each.
This is what I have done so far:

```
    <ul>
        <li>Menu item</li>
        <li>
            Expandable ↓
            <ul>
                <li>Menu</li>
                <li>Menu item</li>
                <li>Menu item long
                    <ul>
                        <li>Menu item long nested1</li>
                        <li>Menu item long nested2</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>E
            <ul>
                <li>A</li>
                <li>B</li>
                <li>C</li>
                <li>D</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            Expands
            <ul>
                <li>Hi.</li>
                <li>Howdy</li>                                    
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    Don't push me down...    
    ul {
        display: table; /* Some CSS magic to make the menu... */
        width: 100%;    /* ...stretch to full width. */

        table-layout: fixed; /* Making menu items equal width */
    }

    li {
        display: table-cell; /* This comes together with ul{display:table} */
        text-align: center;    
    }

    li ul { display: none; } /* Hiding the submenus by default */

    li:hover ul {
        display: block;     /* Show submenus on mouseover...*/
        width: 100%;
        position: relative; /* ...and make them appear below, not inside */
        height:0px; /* Kind of a hack, but it's for a good reason (remove it to see why) */
    }
    li:hover ul li {
        display: block; /* Make submenu items stack vertically */
        width: 100%; /* 100% of parent container */
    }

/* Coloring */
li:nth-child(even){
    background-color: lightblue;    
}
li:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: lightskyblue;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6PTpd/86/

sadly, it can take no more nested items. (the "Menu item long nested2" doesnt appear as in the first example).

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: maybe you are just missing a reset on <ul> : ul {padding:0;margin:0;} http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AqHwh

Comment: your example fails too

Comment: then i guess i misunderstood your probleme from your pieces of code. Your link was more relevant and in this case, Javascript will be necessary to adapt coordonates to keep submenus into windows.

Comment: i think you forget classes and ids of ul elements. http://jsfiddle.net/6PTpd/91/ in this code it works but you should change ul elements classes

Answer (score -1):

You have padding on your li's so if you make it 25% I believe it will simply break to the next line. Try something like 22% for the width and see if that gives you the effect you want.